# Flutter : How to pass a value that is not final to another class?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to open a floating container on Button click of ListView Items. List View items are in an external class, and I want to pass the `int change` value to the main class so that I can call a floating Container in the Screen. I went through the threads here but I could only find answers where they say that I have to make the variable value final. But I can't since the `change` value changes to `change = 1` in the external class I mentioned above.

Here is the code.

```
class ListTileClass extends StatefulWidget {
final Map<String, String> jsonObject;

ListTileClass({this.jsonObject});

@override
_ListTileClassState createState() => _ListTileClassState();
}

class _ListTileClassState extends State<ListTileClass> {
int change = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  children: [
    ListTile(
      title: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: makeWidgetChildren(widget.jsonObject),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}

List<Widget> makeWidgetChildren(jsonObject) {
List<Widget> children = [];
bool _count = true;
jsonObject.keys.forEach(
  (key) => {
    setState(() {
      if (_count == true) {
        children.add(
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                if (change == 0) {
                  change = 1;
                } else {
                  change = 0;
                }
              });
            },
            child: Container(...),
          ),
        );
        _count = false;
      }
    }),
  },
);
return children;
}
}
```

I want to send this Changed `change` value to the main class. I highly appreciate your help!

Comment: i see that you are passing only `jsonObject` to `ListTileClass` class, so where / how `change` is passed ? what exactly do you want to achieve inside `onTap`?

Comment: Inside the ```onTap``` I want to change the value of ```change``` to 1, and send that value to the ```TransactionHistoryScreen``` class where the ```ListTileClass``` is called and build a floating ```Container``` in response to the ```ListViewTile``` click

Comment: so pass a callback in `ListTileClass` constructor - the same way `RaisedButton` passes `onPressed` callback and "call" that callback inside `onTap`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Could you please show me how to do it if it's possible? I'm still new to flutter and trying to get the hang of it

Comment: and for that, I have to make ```change``` final right?  If I make the ```change``` value final, it can't be changed inside the ```setState()``` method right?

Comment: you cannot change any `final` variable once it is initialized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227138/discussion-between-haritha-madhushanka-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use can pass a callback function btw

```
class ListTileClass extends StatefulWidget {
final function callback;
final Map<String, String> jsonObject;

ListTileClass({this.jsonObject, this.callback});

@override
_ListTileClassState createState() => _ListTileClassState();
}

class _ListTileClassState extends State<ListTileClass> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  children: [
    ListTile(
      title: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: makeWidgetChildren(widget.jsonObject),
            ),
            ///this is a sample to use a callback don't mind if it different than your goal
            InkWell(
              onTap:(){
                 /// change value to your value, can be anything
                 callback(value);
              }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}


class YourOtherClass extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_ListTileClassState createState() => _ListTileClassState();
}

class _ListTileClassState extends State<ListTileClass> {
  yourVariable = 0;
  yourFunction(int value){
    setState((){
       yourVariable = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTileClass(
      jsonObject:yourjsonObject,
      callback:yourFunction
    );
  }
}
```

btw istead of using foreach to build a widgets. you can use ListViewBuilder
take a look at this
https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb